# Not able to add the product in the cart in product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, cart

Facing issuse If someone want to add a product to the cart from the list view it works fine. But from a product detail page the Error appears:

We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.

Comment: Hello, we need more information, logs, ajax errors ...

Comment: Hi Manjit, Share log details

Comment: @ZahidH thanks for help its resolved  there are issue related to exact location for var/cache and main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "date

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue occur due to permission denied.

Give permission to generated folder by following commands.

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2

> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/magento

I think it work perfectly!